# wxpython Multiple wx.NumCtrl into data structure for plotting in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I am writing my first gui in wxpython and I am fairly stuck on how to properly get the entered data from the NumCtrl into a data structure that can be easily manipulated by matplotlib to give my desired plot. My GUI template is shown below

[image: GUI template]

Basically for each angle I want to enter the number of counts with (C) and without (U) a collimator in place. When I press the plot button I would then the numbers from each wx.NumCtrl and plot the graph. Currently we enter the counts into a spreadsheet and plot using `ggplot2` from `R`. However I would like to replace this with a more user friendly GUI written with the plotting done within the same script. An example of the desired final plot is given below

[image]

Here is the snippet of the relevant code below:

```
#Set input boxes for results
numctrl_ccm90 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ucm90 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ccp90 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ucp90 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ccm75 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ucm75 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ccp75 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ucp75 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ccm60 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ucm60 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ccp60 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ucp60 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ccm45 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ucm45 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ccp45 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ucp45 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ccm30 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ucm30 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ccp30 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ucp30 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ccm15 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ucm15 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ccp15 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_ucp15 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_cc0 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_uc0 = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
numctrl_fwhm = NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)

fgs.AddMany([(angle),(count_c), (count_u),(angle2),(count_c2), (count_u2),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '-90')),
             (numctrl_ccm90,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_ucm90,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '90')),
             (numctrl_ccp90,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_ucp90,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '-75')),
             (numctrl_ccm75,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_ucm75,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '75')),
             (numctrl_ccp75,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_ucp75,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '-60')),
             (numctrl_ccm60,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_ucm60,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '60')),
             (numctrl_ccp60,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_ucp60,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '-45')),
             (numctrl_ccm45,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_ucm45,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '45')),
             (numctrl_ccp45,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_ucp45,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '-30')),
             (numctrl_ccm30,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_ucm30,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '30')),
             (numctrl_ccp30,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_ucp30,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '-15')),
             (numctrl_ccm15,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_ucm15,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '15')),
             (numctrl_ccp15,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_ucp15,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '0')),
             (numctrl_cc0,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (numctrl_uc0,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '')),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '')),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '')),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '')),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '')),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '')),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'FWHM')),
             (numctrl_fwhm,0,wx.EXPAND,5),
             (wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'deg'))])
```

where `numctrl_ccm90` and `numctrl_ucp90` are the widgets corresponding to the collimated counts at -90deg and the uncollimated counts +90deg etc.

I assume I should create some kind of binding that updates a variable/list/dictionary with the counts for each NumCtrl widget. I am not sure how I should do this and in what format is best for subsequent plotting. For example when I enter 1234 counts in numctrl_ccm90 I would like to store this information as `counts: 1234 collimator:Y Angle: -90.`

When I finish typing in the data I would press the plot button, which would pick up the counts value in each numCtrl box (apart from the fwhm numctrl) and would place all this information in a structure that allows plotting

For the plot - I plot normalised counts for collimated and uncollimated detector versus angle. What is the best way to approach this task. I'm pretty lost at this moment

---

I have my counts in a list of lists now

```
self.angle_list = []
self.angles_list.append([-90,'U',self.numctrl_ucm90.GetValue()])
self.angles_list.append([-75,'U',self.numctrl_ucm75.GetValue()])
```

where each element of angle_list is a list with format [angle, collimator, counts]

Not sure how this helps me plot. What I need is a scatter plot of angle vs counts for the 2 combinations 'U' vs 'C'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having 3 lists of controls, auto-generated, you can then run through the lists in order, once populating a grid sizer and on each plot click run through each again picking up the values to put into two lists of tupples or arrays to supply to plot. e.g.

```
self.Angles = range(-90, 100, 15)
self.Texts = [wx.StaticText(panel, -1, '%d' % a) for a in Angles]
self.CCount = [NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB) for a in Angles]
self.UCount = [NumCtrl(panel,-1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER|wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB) for a in Angles]
```

do your adding to a sizer and in your `OnPlot` method:

```
   Cs = [ctrl.GetValue() for ctrl in self.CCount]
   Us = [ctrl.GetValue() for ctrl in self.UCount]
   plot(zip(Cs, Angles)) # or something similar
```

etc...